# Smart Card Encoder using C# code

Tags: c#, smartcard, rfid

I'm new to this device,

I only tried RFID Mifare RC522 and read its serial ID

This time I'm trying to read the serial ID of RFID card using this Smart Card Encoder **(LA118-M1)** using C# coding in MS Visual Studio.

What class library should I download.

I tried using this code:

```
SerialPort _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM2");
_serialPort.Open();
bool _check = _serialPort.IsOpen;
string _string = _serialPort.ReadLine();
_serialPort.Close();
```

Result:
**Nothing happens**

Comment: What is the "ERROR" here? You should know to put the full Exception and Stacktrace when you ask a "It doesn't work" question.

Comment: sorry, It wasn't an error.

Comment: `string _string = _serialPort.ReadLine();` the program will stop running here but no result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not listening serial port. On your initializing code, open COM port and listen to it (Add `DataReceived` delegate). It would be something like this:

```
public void Open() 
{
   _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM2");
   _serialPort.Open();
   _serialPort.DataReceived +=port_DataReceived;
} 
void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   string line = ((SerialPort)sender).ReadLine();
}
// Close serial port somewhere
```

You can learn more about SerialPort [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/678025/Serial-Comms-in-Csharp-for-Beginners)

Comment: Should I make a function having a parameters of Sender and event?

Comment: is this same with **EventHandler**

Comment: Yes, you can use conventional event handler if you prefer.

Comment: _serialPort.DataReceived += (sender, evt) => 
Error on **sender**

Comment: If the process won't go to the **port_DataReceived**, means theirs no data coming from the **SerialPort** right?

Comment: Maybe. But you need to check `ErrorReceived` event. There may be other conditions which affects communication

Comment: where should I look for it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75775/discussion-between-orifjon-and-see-yah-later).